# How can circles be a subclass of ellipses? Popper

Tags: logic, empiricism, popper

My question comes from: **36 Levels of Universality and Degrees of Precision** from **The Logic of Scientific Discovery**

Excerpt from the chapter 36:

We have the following natural laws:

```
p: All heavenly bodies which move in closed orbits move in circles: or more brieﬂy: All orbits of
heavenly bodies are circles.
q: All orbits of planets are circles.
r: All orbits of heavenly bodies are ellipses.
s: All orbits of planets are ellipses.
```

Moving from p to r, the deegre of precision decreases: ***circles are a proper subclass of ellipses;(.....Me saying: What?????)*** and if r is falsified, oso is p, bus not vice versa.

- Did i just hear right that circles are a proper subclass of ellipses? Circles as I know it are the Class with Subclasses like Ellipses, Parabolas, Hyperboles. Ellipses are the subclass of the class Circles just like Parabolas are a subclass of the class Circles. How can it be the other way around?

Comment: Related: ["Circle–ellipse problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle%E2%80%93ellipse_problem), Wikipedia.

Comment: A circle is an ellipse with eccentricity 0.

Comment: just a taxonomic classification. Open to interpretation.

Comment: If you take a coin, and spin it so you look at it's face with it rotated at 30%, you can see the projection of it is an eclipse.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a mathematics question.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Please be aware that questions and answers are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Anything closed can be edited to bring it within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [MetaPhil](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Nat: What makes you think Popper is wrong? There's a history of science issue here. The Ancient Greeks just assumed planetary orbits were circular, the planets perfect spheres, & geocentrism. Overturning these was key to the renaissance & birth of science. The Ptolmeic system of predicting planetary motion had very complex 'epicycles' to accomodate these ideas. Kepler was able to condense prediction into a simple statement - all 2-body orbits are conic sections, making circular ones an unusual case. As indeed, they are.

Comment: @CriglCragl: That's true; it does seem like a useful thing in classical-logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A circle can be treated as a special class of ellipse:  one in which the two foci coincide.  As such it would be a proper subclass:  all circles are ellipses.  (It is not universally accepted, though.  There are those who hold that to be two, the foci must be separate locations.)

An ellipse is not a special case of a circle, and so not a proper subclass.  Both ellipses and circles, plus parabolas and hyperboles, are proper subclasses of [conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section).